# How to match a sentence with multiple dots using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for questions and answers in a `.txt` file using `re` in Python.
Here is a sample of the text file:

```
1. Xiva xonligining yirik shaharlari xato berilgan javobni aniqlang.
A) Xiva, Kat        
B) Yangi Urganch, Hazorasp    
C) Qo'ng'irot, Xo'jayli   
D) Vazir, Mang'it
2. Xiva xonligi Buxoro amirligi kabi bekliklarga bo'lingan bo'lib, ularni xon tomonidan tayinlangan ......... boshqargan.
A) beklar         
B) noiblar     
C) beklar va to'ralar      
D) biy va beklar
```

Don't mind the language. Questions start with numbers followed by `.` then comes the question body (usually ending with `?`, `.`or `!`)

Then comes the answers from `A` to `D` followed by a closing bracket`)`.

Here is my regex for finding questions: `re"^(\d+\.)?\s+[\"’]?([.]{2,})?[A-Z][^.?!]+((?![.?!][’\"]?\s[\"’]?[A-Z][^.?!]).)+[.?!’\"]+$"`

My problem is when there are multiple dots inside the question body like the question #2, my regex cannot match the whole question body. It rather stops at the first dot it sees. How should I go about this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

> By the way, here is how I am finding the answers with regex: `re"^[a-zA-Z]\)?\s+\w+.+"`
> Suggestions regarding my approach to finding questions and answers are also welcome.

Comment: if you haven't discovered regex101.com (n/a) you should. Your question regex is crazy complicated.  Your answer regex looks a lot simpler, why not use something like that for the question too?

Comment: Thank you, the above regex patterns are created using regex101.com. :)

Comment: Perhaps this pattern will be enough to match the question body in capture group 1 on a single line `^\d+\.[^\S\r\n]*([A-Z].*)` https://regex101.com/r/SPHqmt/1

Answer (score 1):

Since your text file is properly formatted. You can try this for extracting questions:

```
re.findall([\d+][\s\S][\w\W]+[\d\D], t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by matching the digits, dot and the rest of the line. Then optionally repeat all lines that do not start with an uppercase char A-Z followed by `)`

If you only want the question body, you can capture that in a group.

```
^\d+\.[^\S\r\n]*([A-Z].*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]\)).*)*[.?!])
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.[^\S\r\n]*` Match 1+ digits, a `.` and optional whitespace chars without a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z].*` Match an uppercase char A-Z
  - `(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]\)).*)*` Optionally repeat all lines that do not start with an uppercase char A-Z followed by `)`
  - `[.?!]` Match either `.` `?` or `!`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8BhHCY/1)

The pattern to match an answer `^[a-zA-Z]\)?\s+\w+.+` has an optional `)` and can start with a lowercase char a-z as well, which would for example also match `a test`.

If the `)` is always there, you don't have to make it optional, and perhaps matching just `[A-Z]` will make the change to get a false positive a bit smaller.